# iOS IAP Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, iphone

I am testing my app in Xcode . witch means it is not officially up loaded to the appstore. so I can't test the real IAP right? I can only test the sandbox IAP before it officially online in APP store,right?

because when I use the real app id to test the IAP. it always give me error like:

```
_error  NSError *   domain: @"SKErrorDomain" - code: 
 @"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
```

I have checked every thing, all fine. and the sandbox test was also worked fine. so the only reason of the error is the app are not officially online in apptore , am I right?

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator?  You cannot test IAP on the simulator; you must test on a real device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAP can be tested only in sandbox mode with sandbox(test) user account in device.

If you are testing IAP in a sandbox mode with real iTunes apple account in the device, then the error *Cannot Connect to iTunes Store* is shown.

Comment: Thankyou, but what do you mean by "sandbox mode", I think the IAP code is the same except the vertify aip :'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt' and 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt ' right? @Hooda

Comment: sandbox mode simply means development(testing) mode.