# IAP iOS throws Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

IAP was working fine until yesterday, now it shows an error code:0.

```
RMStore: transaction failed with product 100 and error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

"Product Identifier" is correct, app loads the products. Created new sandbox test user and testing on not signed in Simulator device. 
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here:
[iOS IAP Cannot connect to iTunes Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748053/ios-iap-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

> Are you testing on a real device or the simulator? You cannot test IAP on the simulator; you must test on a real device – Paulw11 Aug 18 '17 at 3:38

Signed out on real device and tested there.